# Gnome terminal: how to get the existing title?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is it possible to get the existing title of a current gnome-terminal session? I know how to *set* the title, but how do I *get* it? Google failed me here, and there's no mention of anything like that in any gnome docs. Much appreciated.

EDIT: Solutions that do not involve the installation of external packages like `xdotools`, `xprop` or `wmctrl` are preferred.

Comment: `xprop` is installed on Ubuntu by default :) , edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*if* `xdotool` is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

and assuming the current session's window is in front (since the command needs to be typed), just run:

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
```

#### How to get the current session's title without installing additional software

*If* you'd like to do it without installing anything additional, you can use:

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root 32x '\t$0' _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -f 2) _NET_WM_NAME | awk -F\" '{ print $2 }'
```

(`xprop` is installed by default)

Or only using `xprop` and `awk`:

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk '{ print $NF }') _NET_WM_NAME | awk -F\" '{ print $2 }'
```

explanation:

1. to get the active window (line) with `xprop`:

   ```
   xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW
   ```
2. to extract the window `id` (which is the last string of the line):

   ```
   awk '{ print $NF }'
   ```
3. then produce the line with the window name, by the produced `id`:

   ```
   xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk '{ print $NF }') _NET_WM_NAME
   ```
4. Finally, split the produced line by the delimiter `"`, produce the second section:

   ```
   awk -F\" '{ print $2 }'
   ```

#### Edit

Or, the other way around, only using `xprop`and `cut`, as suggested by @Hannu (slightly faster):

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root 32x '\t$0' _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -f2) _NET_WM_NAME | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Comment: `xprop -id $(xprop -root 32x '\t$0' _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -f 2) _NET_WM_NAME | cut -d'"' -f2`

Comment: @Hannu Thanks for the suggestion! edited it into my answer.  Using `cut` turns out to be slightly faster then `awk`